# Arduino library making

Tags: arduino-ide, library

I make my own library for arduino.

The file structure is like below.

```
AAA - README.md
    - examples - A - A.ino
               - B - B.ino
    - AAA.h
    - BBB.h
    - CCC.h
    - BBB.cpp
    - CCC.cpp
```

It works well. But I want to grouping a library source files like below.

```
AAA - same as above
    - src - AAA.h
          - BBB.h
          - CCC.h
          - BBB.cpp
          - CCC.cpp
```

It doesn't work at all.

Arduino IDE shows the message

> Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library.

But, WiFi101 library was made by src folder. Why isn't it possible for mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your library structure is like this because the structure you described above would not cause that error:

```
AAA
|_src
    |_AAA.h
    |_BBB.h
    |_CCC.h
    |_BBB.cpp
    |_CCC.cpp
```

To be considered valid by the Arduino IDE, a library must either have a .h file in the root folder or a library.properties file if you are using the [1.5 library format](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#15-library-format-rev-21). Putting all the source files in the `src` subfolder means your library is in the 1.5 library format. So you need to add a library.properties file in the root of the library formatted as described here: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#libraryproperties-file-format. Then your library should look like this:

```
AAA
|_library.properties
|_src
    |_AAA.h
    |_BBB.h
    |_CCC.h
    |_BBB.cpp
    |_CCC.cpp
```